# MongoDB InsertBatch JObject - Serialization error

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, json.net

I'm using a .NET application and trying to insert to a MongoDB.
I'm using InsertBatch and passing on to it IEnumerable of Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

The error i'm getting:

```
{"Serializer DictionarySerializer<String, JToken> expected serialization options of type DictionarySerializationOptions, not DocumentSerializationOptions."}
```

My code is:

```
private void InsertItemsToMongo(IEnumerable<JObject> list)
{
    MongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var myDb = mongo.GetServer().GetDatabase("MyDatabase");
    if (!myDb.CollectionExists("MyStuff");
        myDb.CreateCollection("MyStuff");

    MongoCollection<JObject> myCollection = myDb.GetCollection<JObject>("MyStuff");
    myCollection.InsertBatch(list);
}
```

The error is thrown at the InsertBatch line.

If you need any other info please provide, I provided just what I deemed relevant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant insert JObject into mongo, you have to convert it to BsonDocument

```
var bsonlist = new List<BsonDocument>();
foreach (var obj in list)
{
    bsonlist.Add(BsonDocument.Parse(obj));
}

var myCollection = database.GetCollection("MyStuff");
var doc = BsonArray.Create(bsonlist);
myCollection.InsertBatch(doc);
```