# MongoDB Issues Deserializing JArray

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, json.net

I'm getting following exceptions:

- `An error occurred while deserializing the Value property of class ExampleClass: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' does not have a suitable constructor or Add method.`
- `MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' does not have a suitable constructor or Add method.`

And it looks like the issue happens when it tries to read an entry from MongoDB, which has this "Value" key:

```
"Value": {
    "_t": "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed",
    "_v": [{
            "_t": "JValue",
            "_v": []
    }, {
            "_t": "JValue",
            "_v": []
    }]
}
```

"Value" is an object: `public object Value { get; set; }`.

I'm a bit stuck here since was researching this issue for 1.5 days now, so any insights appreciated!

PS.: It looks like `"_v": []` are empty, but it shouldn't be, probably meaning that it fails to insert entry properly due to same exception?..

Comment: It looks like you tried to insert a `JToken` from Json.NET into MongoDB by serializing it as a POCO.  In the process all sorts of .NET **type information** got added into the database -- but the actual `JValue` values were omitted.  This is not a good approach.  Since a `JToken` represents a JSON document you should add it to MongoDB as such.  See e.g. [MongoDB InsertBatch JObject - Serialization error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27471220/3744182) or [Convert Newtosoft JObject directly to BsonDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62080252/3744182).