# JToken does not have a suitable constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb, json.net

I am trying to list my data from my mongodb database but while calling the method this exception is appearing.

```
System.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the accomplishment_projects property of class LinkedInExporter.Domain.Models.Root: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' does not have a suitable constructor or Add method.
 ---> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' does not have a suitable constructor or Add method.
```

My code is like this

```
public class DataService : IDataService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Root> _collection;
        private readonly ITeamMemberService _teamMemberService;
        public DataService(ITeamMemberService teamMemberService)
        {
            _teamMemberService = teamMemberService;

            var mongoClient = new MongoClient("connstring"
            );
            var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase("Database");

            _collection= mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Root>("Collection");
        }
        public async Task<List<Root>> GetAllData() =>
            await _collection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
    }
```

And the root object is like this

```
public class Root
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic_url { get; set; }
    public string background_cover_image_url { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public List<Experience> experiences { get; set; }
    public List<Education> education { get; set; }
}
```

I am unable to find a solution please help.

Comment: [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) is the abstract base class for all Newtonsoft's [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) document object model.  If, somewhere in your data model, you have a declared `public JToken accomplishment_projects { get; set; }` property, you may get this exception.  But the `Root` shown in your question doesn't have an `accomplishment_projects` property, so can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611979/mongodb-issues-deserializing-jarray#comment116009379_65611979) to [MongoDB Issues Deserializing JArray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65611979).

Comment: I have not but I have things like List<object> etc

Comment: Then try to make a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.  Chances are you deserialized some JSON with newtonsoft, and an `object` property was deserialized as a `JObject`, then you stored that in MongoDB without writing any sort of converter and, as a result, it was corrupted during storage and throws an exception during retrieval.  But we need a [mcve] showing the full sequence of events to help.

Comment: Yeah it was just as you said some data was deserializes as JObject which throws an exception. Thanks for helping